# how to configure SpringJDBC with jee:jndi-lookup

Tags: java, spring, web.xml, spring-jdbc

I have a question in Spring JDBC settings. that more needed me ?

missing some other configuration

```
    <jee:jndi-lookup id=" wasDataSource "
                     jndi-name="jdbc/xxxx"
                     cache="true"
                     resource-ref="true"
                     lookup-on-startup="false"
                     proxy-interface="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

Dao:

```
public class BinnacleDaoImpl implements BinnacleDao {

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public String getFindBitacoraForDate(){
            //ArrayList value = new ArrayList();

            FOP fop =  jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
                    "SELECT DESCRIPTION_HTML FROM PHUBUSR.FOP WHERE ID = ?;",
                    new Object[]{1},
                    new RowMapper<FOP>() {
                        public FOP mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                            FOP fop = new FOP();
                            fop.setDescripcionHtml(rs.getString("DESCRIPTION_HTML"));
                            return fop;
                        }
                    });
            System.out.println(fop.getDescripcionHtml());

            return null;
        }
```

I'd appreciate your help

Comment: What is your question/issue?

Comment: JdbcTemplate time execution comes as null

Comment: Where is your `JdbcTemplate` config?

Comment: I have setup a file xml spring and also have imported the library by maven

Comment: Can you show us the config? You do not need the method `setJdbcTemplate`. Are you scanning this Dao class?

Comment: <bean id="wasDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
                <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/xxxx"/>
                <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false"/>
                <property name="cache" value="true"/>
                <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
        </bean>

        <bean class="cl.cencosud.hubpagos.dao.daoimpl.BinnacleDaoImpl" name="BinnacleDaoImpl"/>

Comment: Well I'm not sure if you are actually scanning your Dao class.  You need a `@Component` type annotation for Spring to do anything with `@Autowired` at the top of your class and you never answered if you have that. Then you can use something like the method you have but grab the DataSource since that is what you have configured in the xml and make the template out of that. I would read up on the Spring [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html) first to get a better understanding. See "JdbcTemplate best practices" section

Comment: It was not my kind of service scans the spring, and working with jersey, thanks for your time